# Python Client / Server with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I cant figure out why the client is not communicating with the Server (2 seperate jupyter notebooks with own kernel), no error messages - any suggestions?

the following code is working (without multiprocessing):

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 50000

def start_server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print ('waiting for client')
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('client connected @', addr[0], 'port:', addr[1])
    return conn               


Server0 = start_server()
```

Client:

```
import socket


HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 50000


data = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)              
s.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))                                          
while True:                                                       
    byte_message = s.recv(1024)                                    
    string_message = byte_message.decode('utf8')
    header, time, data = string_message.split(' ')
    if header == 'close':
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        s.close()
        print('client connection shut down')
        header = ''
    elif header == '<<':
        print(time,float(data))
    else:
        pass
```

As soon as I pack the client into a function and run it as a process, client and server do not connect anymore(no error is given, and the server doesent get to this line:
`print('client connected @', addr[0], 'port:', addr[1])`

not working client:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing


HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 50000

def client():
    data = []
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)              
    s.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))                                          
    while True:                                                       
        byte_message = s.recv(1024)                                    
        string_message = byte_message.decode('utf8')
        header, time, data = string_message.split(' ')
        if header == 'close':
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            s.close()
            print('client connection shut down')
            header = ''
       elif header == '<<':
            print(time,float(data))
       else:
            pass


client_process =  multiprocessing.Process(target= client)   
client_process.start()
```

Comment: connect_ex is the same as connect but it doesn't throw errors if something goes wrong. Why don't you want it to throw errors if something goes wrong?

Comment: also I wonder if the output is going to your terminal or something and not getting caught by Jupyter

Comment: i used connect_ex to get an error indicator back e.g. 0 for sucess aso, to do something later with it.   Now,  I put the server and client code into a separate script and was running it with pycharm, i got an error on the client side : ````RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module ````  and changed the call for the ....

Comment: ... process to ````if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_process =  multiprocessing.Process(target= client)   
    client_process.start() ```` now server and client are connecting, but still have no idea how to implement it in jupyter lab

Comment: @chuubaka Under jupyter lab, strange but true, your target, `client` in this case, must be imported from another file. Put that function in a file such as *workers.py* and then `from workers import client`. I am assuming *workers.py* will be in the same directory as your .ipynb file.

Comment: @Booboo, i tried but still no success, the server is still at ````print ('waiting for client')````. In the client notebook (own kernel) the cell does not throw any errors